# How to give a view focus when my app launches?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

how can I choose the view which is active when I start my app?
I searched in the Interface Builder but found nothing.
Perhaps there is a chance like `[view setActive]`?

so long

Comment: What do you mean by “item”? What do you mean by “active”?

Comment: For example an NSTextField  set to be on focus so that I can write directly in there and don't need to click on it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the view as the value of the window's `initialFirstResponder` outlet. When the window is ordered in the first time, the window will make whatever responder is in that outlet the first responder, which is how you give a responder (such as a view) focus.

Comment: For the blindfolded (like me): rightclick on window in the docview -> drag the outlet `initialFirstResponder` to the item you want to be on focus.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the view was in a different NIB, and the chosen solution doesn't apply. For anyone looking for another solution, you can use NSWindow's makeFirstResponder method in your application delegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching: method.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    self.schemaOutlineController = [[PBSchemaOutlineController alloc] init];

    [self.masterView addSubview:self.schemaOutlineController.view];
    [self.detailView addSubview:self.schemaOutlineController.schemaObjectViewController.view];

    [self.window makeFirstResponder:self.schemaOutlineController.searchField];
}
```